# What's the utility of SSH in a hosting?

Tags: ssh, hosting, shared-hosting

Can anyone explain to me in layman what's [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) (Secure Shell) in a shared hosting?

I know you can access the web hosting server remotely using a command line interface using an application like [Putty](http://www.putty.org/). But does it give you have *more* access to the server or it's another way of creating directories or uploading files and stuff like that? Or you can install extensions or do more advanced things?

Thanks.

Comment: "... does it give you have more access to the server" More than what?

Comment: Than using cPanel and FTP access, for example.

Comment: FTP is insecure, the whole Internet gets to see your password every time you use it. SSH has a secure replacement called SFTP, programs like FileZilla support it. SSH can also authenticate without passwords, using key files (which adds more security yet, and can be used in situations where you don't want to store passwords usually; plus other stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the restriction the host sets, but it often lets you run command line utilities, often used for things like batch processing files, changing file permissions, etc.

In other words, SSH gives you access to do most things you'd be able to do if you were logged in to the machine locally (without root access).

Comment: +1 Very well explained ... in layman terms that is, hehe.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a security layer that encrypts all data flowing to and from the server so other people can't read it's contents.  This is especially useful if you are dealing with sensitive information.